# QGraphicsTextItem: how to make its mouse moving area wider?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

I have a `QGraphicsTextItem` on my `QGraphicsScene`. I made it editable, and I also want to sometimes move it by mouse (and select by mouse too).

But to move it, I should aim my mouse pointer in a few pixels between the text area and `QGraphicsTextItem`'s border.

[image: The selection area is too narrow!!!!!]

Cannot you tell me: **how to make this narrow padding at least two times wider?**

Here is the code:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsItem, QGraphicsTextItem


if __name__ == "__main__":

    #########################################
    sys._excepthook = sys.excepthook
    def exception_hook(exctype, value, traceback):
        sys._excepthook(exctype, value, traceback)
        sys.exit(1)
    sys.excepthook = exception_hook
    ##########################################



    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView()
    view.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
    view.setMouseTracking(True)
    view.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.RubberBandDrag)

    scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()

    text_item = QGraphicsTextItem("Hell yeah!!!")
    text_item.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.TextEditorInteraction)
    text_item.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable | QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable | QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
    scene.addItem(text_item)

    view.setScene(scene)
    view.show()

    app.setStyle("fusion")

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Could you explain me better?

Comment: Well, I want to move the QGraphicsTextItem by mouse. If I aim the mouse to the center of the item, press-and-hold left button and them move the mouse — there starts text selection. So I should aim to the few pixels between the border of the text selection area and the border of the QGraphicsTextItem. It is really narrow, and I want to make it wider.